# Different behaviour between oracle and postgres regarding alter table primary key command

Tags: postgresql, index

In Oracle 11g, when you write

```
alter table abc add constraint abc_pk primary key (one, two, three);
```

Automatically an index for one, two, three is added.

In PostgreSQL 9.5, when you do the same, no index is added.

Is there anything I can add to the command and have the same behaviour as with Oracle?

[image]

Comment: Which exact version of Postgres do you have and which OS? This is not reproducible in my machine.

Comment: I added a pgadmin picture where you can see that there is a primary key constraint but no index ("Indexes (0)").

Comment: That's the PgAdmin that is not showing it there. The index exists. Not sure why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An index is added in PostgreSQL, too, when a `PRIMARY KEY` or a `UNIQUE` constraint is created, as it is clearly stated in the docs. See [`CREATE TABLE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-createtable.html):

> PostgreSQL **automatically creates an index** for each `unique` constraint and `primary key` constraint to enforce uniqueness. Thus, it is not necessary to create an index explicitly for primary key columns. ...

Tested:

**Version:**

```
x=# select version();
                                             version                                             
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 9.5.2 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2, 64-bit
(1 row)
```

**Create the table and show the structure:**

```
x=# create table abc (one int not null, two int not null, three int not null);
CREATE TABLE

x=# \d abc
      Table "public.abc"
 Column |  Type   | Modifiers 
--------+---------+-----------
 one    | integer | not null
 two    | integer | not null
 three  | integer | not null
```

**Add the `primary key` constraint  and show the structure again:**

```
x=# alter table abc add constraint abc_pk primary key (one, two, three);
ALTER TABLE

x=# \d abc
      Table "public.abc"
 Column |  Type   | Modifiers 
--------+---------+-----------
 one    | integer | not null
 two    | integer | not null
 three  | integer | not null
Indexes:
    "abc_pk" PRIMARY KEY, btree (one, two, three)
```

---

As for PgAdmin, looks like it doesn't show these automatically created indexes in the Indexes list. That's a decision its developers took. See an old discussion (from 2004!) about the exact same issue:

[[pgAdmin-Support] Indexes generated for primary key are not shown by PgAdminIII.](http://grokbase.com/t/postgresql/pgadmin-support/041wj72rwh/indexes-generated-for-primary-key-are-not-show-by-pgadminiii)